# How to print elements of a set in Python?

Tags: python, printing, overriding, human-readable

I have a `set` of objects that I want to print in readable form. The objects' class overrides `__str__`, which should be used for printing. However, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python), `__repr__` is used when printing containers, which is not what I want.

The posts advice to use `print "["+", ".join(l)+"]"` for lists doesn't work for sets. So what can I do?

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work for sets? It'll have square brackets that are kind of misleading, but it should work just as well for sets as it does for lists (assuming you have strings in there).

Comment: Briefly: `print(*myset)` or `print(', '.join(map(str, myset)))`.

Comment: Thanks, `print(', '.join(map(str, myset)))` works. But `print("{"+", ".join(myset)+"}")` doesn't because it doesn't contain strings?

Comment: That's right. `print` can print anything, but `str.join` only works on strings.